# General reduceInitial function crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm building a dc.js / d3.js dashboard in which I often have to make crossfilter groups containing a quantity for each key and a percentage of the total value for each key. That is why I want to make generic reduceAdd, reduceRemove and reduceInitial functions. I managed doing the first 2, but I don't understand reduceInitial behaviour :

```
function reduceAdd(dim,grouping,col) {
    var keys = getKeys(dim); // get the keys name in an array of string
    return function(p,v) {
        p.total += parseInt(v[col]); // get the running total
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if(v[grouping] == keys[i]) {p[keys[i]] += +v[col];}
            p[keys[i]+"perc"] = p[keys[i]]/p.total; // calculate a percentage for ech key
        }
        return p;
    }
}

function reduceRemove(dim,grouping,col) {
    var keys = getKeys(dim);
    return function(p,v) {
        p.total -= parseInt(v[col]);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if(v[grouping] == keys[i]) {p[keys[i]] -= +v[col];}
            p[keys[i]+"perc"] = p[keys[i]]/p.total;
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

This is the working non generic `function reduceInitFC() { 
 return {total:0, LILOU:0, MARIUS:0,ORIANE:0,LILOUperc:0,MARIUSperc:0,ORIANEperc:0};
}`

This is what I tried :

```
function reduceInit(dim) { 
    var keys = getKeys(dim);
    var initArray= {};
    initArray["total"] = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        initArray[keys[i]] = 0;
        initArray[keys[i]+"perc"] = 0;
    }
    console.log(initArray); // (1)
    console.log({total:0, LILOU:0, MARIUS:0,ORIANE:0,LILOUperc:0,MARIUSperc:0,ORIANEperc:0});
    return function() {
            return initArray; 

    }   
}
```

The result is :
(1) The output gives 0 for all the keys every two iterations and some non zero values for the other iterations
When I use this function the resulting values in the group are constant respect with the keys what is not the case in reality and not the case when I hand write the zero values.

If anyone can help, it would be super kind and useful.

Best,
Theo

Comment: What is `getKeys`? Can you post a working example? I suspect that using `getKeys` like this is causing bugs in `reduceAdd` and `reduceRemove` that you aren't realizing are there and that in `reduceInit` there aren't yet any keys so you don't get any values, but it's impossible to tell without a working example where I can see what `getKeys` does and exactly when the group is created.

Comment: Ah, I take it back about `getKeys` introducing bugs. Though it won't update when new data is added, and that's actually good. If it did update you will have bugs. In any case, still need a working example in order to have much chance of diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I will maybe add a fiddle but it will take a bit of time, btw here is my getKey function, it's just returning an array containing the all the keys of a dimension :

Comment: `function getKeys(dim) {
 var len = dim.group().all().length;
 var keys = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   keys[i] = dim.group().all()[i].key;
 }
 return keys;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think your reduceInit looks fine, but I don't think this is possible through the reduce. The reduce calculates totals incrementally -- and don't make sense until the group runs through all the rows in the dimension. So the percentages for each key can't be calculated until reduce is finished. (Likewise, while the reduce can be used to calculate averages across a single key's values, they can't be used for averages across all keys because that would be dependent on the reduced total.) *(UPDATED, also see this answer's comments)*

But since you already have the reduced total and the total for the key / category, you can calculate the percentage in your chart's valueAccessor.

```
function valueAccessor(d){
  return d.value[keyName] / d.value.total
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misspoke, the only problem I have is to generalize the reduceInital. When I use a reduceInitial function that is just returning hardcoded 0 values, the calculation works well :)

Comment: This is correct - you should calculate averages in the `valueAccessor` and not in the reducer, mostly for performance reasons.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that Ethan, can you explain how it impacts the performance ? Thank you for your help both of you !

Comment: The reduce functions run for every record that is added and for every record that goes in and out of a filter. The average only needs to be calculated at the time you want to display it, so there is no need to do that calculation repeatedly and it shouldn't go in the reducer. Stick a `console.log` in your `reduceAdd` function and you'll see how often it is called.

Comment: But is it not happening the same thing in the background when we calculate it in the group function ?

Comment: Performance would probably be an issue. Also I think your `getKeys` function could probably be stored as a constant beforehand -- are the keys changing that often? If they are I don't recommend getting them by running a group on the dimension.

Comment: @Teo, leaving performance aside, I updated the answer to respond to some of your questions about the reduce.